# Amocrm Api php почему отправляется пустое тело запроса?

Tags: php, api, crm

Авторизовался через Oauth2.0 пытаюсь добавить сделку прилетает сообщение Bad request: 400 Request data can not be empty. Вот код:

```
<?php
$subdomain = 'xxx'; //Поддомен нужного аккаунта
$link = 'https://' . $subdomain . '.amocrm.ru/api/v4/leads'; //Формируем URL для запроса
/** Получаем access_token из вашего хранилища */
$access_token = 'xxx';
/** Формируем заголовки */
$headers = [
    'Content-Type:application/json',
    'Authorization: Bearer ' . $access_token,

];
$leads= array('name' => 'new leads');

/**
 * Нам необходимо инициировать запрос к серверу.
 * Воспользуемся библиотекой cURL (поставляется в составе PHP).
 * Вы также можете использовать и кроссплатформенную программу cURL, если вы не программируете на PHP.
 */
$curl = curl_init(); //Сохраняем дескриптор сеанса cURL
/** Устанавливаем необходимые опции для сеанса cURL  */
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'amoCRM-oAuth-client/1.0');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $link);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($leads));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
$out = curl_exec($curl); //Инициируем запрос к API и сохраняем ответ в переменную
$code = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($curl);
/** Теперь мы можем обработать ответ, полученный от сервера. Это пример. Вы можете обработать данные своим способом. */
$code = (int)$code;
$errors = [
    400 => 'Bad request',
    401 => 'Unauthorized',
    403 => 'Forbidden',
    404 => 'Not found',
    500 => 'Internal server error',
    502 => 'Bad gateway',
    503 => 'Service unavailable',
];

print_r(json_decode($out, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE));
try {
    /** Если код ответа не успешный - возвращаем сообщение об ошибке  */
    if ($code < 200 || $code > 204) {
        throw new Exception(isset($errors[$code]) ? $errors[$code] : 'Undefined error', $code);
    }
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    die('Ошибка: ' . $e->getMessage() . PHP_EOL . 'Код ошибки: ' . $e->getCode());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

У меня сработал данный метод добавления сделки

```
<?php
$subdomain = 'xxx'; //Поддомен нужного аккаунта
$link = 'https://' . $subdomain . '.amocrm.ru/api/v2/leads'; //Формируем URL для запроса
/** Получаем access_token из вашего хранилища */
$access_token = 'xxx';

/** id ответственного за сделки юзера */
$responsible_user_id = 'xxx';

/** Формируем заголовки */
$headers = [
    'Authorization: Bearer ' . $access_token
];

$leads['add'] = array(
    array(
        'name' => 'Бумага',
        'created_at' => 1298904164,
        'status_id' => 7087609,
        'sale' => 600200,
        'responsible_user_id' => $responsible_user_id,
    ),
);

/**
 * Нам необходимо инициировать запрос к серверу.
 * Воспользуемся библиотекой cURL (поставляется в составе PHP).
 * Вы также можете использовать и кроссплатформенную программу cURL, если вы не программируете на PHP.
 */
$curl = curl_init(); //Сохраняем дескриптор сеанса cURL
/** Устанавливаем необходимые опции для сеанса cURL  */
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'amoCRM-oAuth-client/1.0');
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_URL, $link);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($leads));
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
$out = curl_exec($curl); //Инициируем запрос к API и сохраняем ответ в переменную
$code = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($curl);
/** Теперь мы можем обработать ответ, полученный от сервера. Это пример. Вы можете обработать данные своим способом. */
$code = (int)$code;
$errors = [
    400 => 'Bad request',
    401 => 'Unauthorized',
    403 => 'Forbidden',
    404 => 'Not found',
    500 => 'Internal server error',
    502 => 'Bad gateway',
    503 => 'Service unavailable',
];

try
{
    /** Если код ответа не успешный - возвращаем сообщение об ошибке  */
    if ($code < 200 || $code > 204) {
        throw new Exception(isset($errors[$code]) ? $errors[$code] : 'Undefined error', $code);
    }
}
catch(\Exception $e)
{
    die('Ошибка: ' . $e->getMessage() . PHP_EOL . 'Код ошибки: ' . $e->getCode());
}
```